# C++- Help (error: expected unqualified-id before 'return')

Tags: c++

I have throughly looked through all streams containing this question and have found no answer that helps me solve this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int age; 
    {
        cout << "What is your age?";
        cin >> age;
    }
    if (age > 10)
    {
        if (age >= 17)
            cout << "You are legally allowed to drive- woohoo!";
    }
    else
    {
        if (age<=10)
            cout<< "You are a child- silly to even ponder this fact";
    }

    if (age < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error- liar!";   
    }
}
return 0;
```

When trying to run this program, the debugger says that there is an unqualified-id before return- I have tried removing/adding semi-colons and brackets, and even tried to change the way the lines are spaced..

Can someone help?

Thank you very much...

Comment: The `return 0;` should be within `}`

Answer (score 2):

Your `return` statement must be within a function definition. You cannot have a `return` statement in the global scope

```
int main(){
   .....
}
return 0;   // <-- wrong
```

It should be:

```
int main(){
   .....
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just look at your code again. I've edited and indented it properly.

Now you can clearly see that `return 0;` is outside of the `int main() {}`, which is incorrect. It must be before that last `}`.

---

Also,

```
int age; 
{
    cout << "What is your age?";
    cin >> age;
}
```

makes no sense. It's legal, but `{}` are redundant here. You can replace it with

```
int age; 
cout << "What is your age?";
cin >> age;
```